# Magento 2 Extension submission to Marketplace

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace

Problem is related to Marketplace extension submission.

- Whenever i submit a new extension, it response back with this error message "An error occurred, please try again later." with no other information, where to check or fix problem.
- This is a Magento 2 module,
- This situation is only for my two modules out of 13. dont know why its happening. i removed all directories and files from except **registration.php & composer.json & module.xml** But error remains same.
- Contacted the Marketplace but no clue yet after 40 days now m here,

  Here is screen-shot attached.

  May anyone faced this kind of problem. 
  [image]